# PowerApps Lookup Multiple Values

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-formula

I have a PowerApps form.  It has three dropdowns where users can select values for Duration, Impact and Probability.  From that I would like the form (and its associated SharePoint List) to display the Risk Level associated with the choices made.  The risk level is defined in a separate table which I've connected to the same PowerApps form.  This table has 30 rows (permutations) and 4 columns - Duration, Impact, Probability and Risk Level.  I may want to integrate Alternative into the logic eventually - see screenshot.

I have tried a number of different approaches including nested ifs (perhaps too many?), search and lookup, but am not getting anywhere.

Had results including wrong record type and getting syntax errors.  I am not sure how to correctly reference the second table to be looked up based on values in the first table.  In Excel I'd use xlookup to achieve the same.

Comment: Hello @EnCee, welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to create questions that have better chance of getting answers. In your case, you mention a screenshot but it's not there. It would be good to show the syntax that you tried and any errors that you are getting as well.